# ModSecurity: Error reading request body: Connection reset by peer

Tags: apache, mediawiki, mod-security

We have a MediaWiki hosted and if i want to edit the common.css file for some small changes i get a ERR_CONNECTION_RESET from my browser.
The error.log from Apacha says its a ModSecure problem:

```
[Thu Jul 27 11:00:16.253269 2023] [:error] [pid 522278:tid 140286206387776] [client 138.232.72.64:2820] [client 138.232.72.64] ModSecurity: Error reading request body: Connection reset by peer [hostname "fila.feuerwehr-landeck.at"] [uri "/index.php"] [unique_id "ZMIyIMzlGwCCOoqHoneh4AAAAk0"], referer: http://fila.feuerwehr-landeck.at/index.php?title=MediaWiki:Common.css&action=edit
```

I tried different clients, with different IPs and Browser - same problem

thanks
Manuel

Comment: Can you try setting log level in Apache to debug?

Comment: In absence of additional logs, this is only ModSecurity being verbose about losing aconnection. This is a connection problem and ModSec is the one to complain (-> "Connection reset by peer"). I'm very confident it has nothing to do with ModSecurity. -- CRS dev on duty